# Jenkins Ext email showing address not configured yet - even after setting up the System admins email

Tags: email, jenkins

Jenkins Version : 2.251

I have configured the **Extended E-mail Notification** in my Jenkins and setup the **System Admin e-mail address** under Jenkins Location like this (e.g. "Jenkins Daemon <foo@acme.org>").

When I do a **Test configuration by sending test e-mail**, I'm getting a test mail from Jenkins with proper address.
But when my Job triggers a mail after completion, its coming as **address not configured yet**.

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you trigger the email? Are you using piplines or a freestyle project?

Comment: I'm using freestyle project.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.
I was able to do it successfully with:

Freestyle job:
Add Post-build action > Editable email notification( from Email Extension plugin) >
The "project from" field > thesender@test.comzz

Declarative pipeline:

```
emailext body: 'abcd', from: 'thesender@test.comzz', replyTo: 'justTest@test.comzz', subject: 'test1', to: 'youremail@test.comzz'
```